# date conversion in teradata

Tags: date, type-conversion, teradata, varchar

I am using this query 
select * from temp  where cast (DateStart as varchar(12))

so if we count this for today it should give records with date less than '2014-07-17'

but the above query is giving all records even the records with date greater than the above given date.

datatype datestart : varchar(10)

how can I convert above to give records only less than the calculated date?
thanks.

Comment: Can you give us an example of a date that is being returned incorrectly?  Is the data type of the column varchar?  Why are you casting it?

Comment: @Andrew returned in format  09/09/14 other example 07/25/14 for all other cases it returns invalid timestamp. Datatype of column is varchar

Answer (score 0):

i got a solution for this it was converting all date like 1914 instead of 2014 and that is why returning all records. So solution is :
  cast ( DateStarted  as date format 'mm/dd/yy')  + INTERVAL '100' YEAR